# Play part of video on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am developer a website in Ruby on Rails. I have a page where I display the videos that I retrieve from the database. Video links are saved in the database and I retrieve them in my controller. In my view, I am trying to display all the videos and play part of the video on hover. The issue that I am facing is that, only first video is played on hover. All other videos are not played. I am using Javascript to add hover effect. Here is snippet of my view:

```
<% @clips.each do |clip| %>
<video width="200px" height="200px">
  <source src=<%= clip.custom_video_link%>>
</video>
```

Here is my Javascript code:

```
<script>
    const video = document.querySelector("video");

    function startPreview() {
      video.muted = true;
      video.currentTime = 1;
      video.playbackRate = 0.5;
      video.play();
    }

    function stopPreview() {
      video.currentTime = 0;
      video.playbackRate = 1;
      video.pause();
    }

    let previewTimeout = null;

    video.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
      startPreview();
      previewTimeout = setTimeout(stopPreview, 4000);
    });

    video.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
      clearTimeout(previewTimeout);
      previewTimeout = null;
      stopPreview();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Do you get multiple `<video>` tags in the output in DOM?

Comment: Sort of. I have multiple videos in my page. The <% @clips.each do |clip| %> retrieves multiple clips. Currently the hover effect is shown only on the first video.